# How do I call a function using a generic args variable with a derived Parameters type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

When calling a function `n` with arguments spread from a variable of type Parameters<`n`>, everything seems to be in order as you might expect. But it seems as though adding a layer of indirection throws a wrench in things, e.g.

```js
    type EventSchema = {
      'performTask': (task: string, data: number) => void
    };  

    // Mapping keys of EventSchema to arrays of listener methods
    const listeners: {[p in keyof EventSchema]: EventSchema[p][]} = {
      'performTask': []
    };

    export function emitGlobalEvent<K extends keyof EventSchema>(event: K, ...args: Parameters<EventSchema[K]>) {
      listeners[event].forEach((listener) => {
        listener(...args); // Error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
      });
    }
```

When changing the `...args` type to explicitly be `(task: string, data: number) => void`, no error is thrown. It seems as though the compiler is able to infer the type correctly, and it is a tuple, so why would this error occur here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to assure TS that it is safe to pass `...args` to `listener`, I think it worth provide your function with `listeners` argument:

```js
type EventSchema = {
    'performTask': (task: string, data: number) => void
};

// Mapping keys of EventSchema to arrays of listener methods
const listeners: { [p in keyof EventSchema]: EventSchema[p][] } = {
    'performTask': []
};


export function emitGlobalEvent<
    K extends keyof EventSchema,
    Listeners extends Record<K, Array<(...args: Parameters<EventSchema[K]>) => void>>
>(listeners: Listeners, event: K, ...args: Parameters<EventSchema[K]>) {
    listeners[event].forEach((listener) => {
        listener(...args); // no error
    });
}

emitGlobalEvent(listeners, 'performTask', 'task', 42)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAygYwBYQLYEMoC8UA3gLABQUVUA5JAE4BmA9vdgCq4DOA1jQFxQAFMG49BXYPQCWiAOYAaKABNcowYgCu2AEYR6ASkIA%20KHGbTlFAL4BuChQD0jqAFlcYMLLlQeEEFxQzIywCMjoWHhQwMxQuPT0uAFBIQA20pJI%20lDYEMAYzMpcFGjMiJJQ6ZmI%20lyCxFAA2mBQsr7%20waFIqJg4uAC6gvDdEX3N-Y39UNaEJBTUtAwsbJy8Ak39NvbkFKCQUADyswAK8bi5wLUAPMPhvXiNdPrLHGI0-cYO5BAAHmCswCgjE0iDQwGkZSgOGkwAA4qlmDpcKlbsArvNqABpKE-S6IIrtECdVGjPAKDFUAAyGTxtRxeIJACUIKV6MorpilABBBJJK5CAB0QvicjqUFOiQu1xJ91wjUxHyMBFM5ksxk%205GMQiqtPoYup1VqSggYWAgk5UCFApFYol5zy0tNpLlCuMRjIlGoOqyesaJu6-QFyxguEwQm1NJ9StMHoWC29NXoguF9FFBlsUGcsASrEEXKgXDA9AguGUcVT2m6OU0FQgMKw9CgGFwCDi0U0YFS0D20FYUD0UDA3C4EDLMTbxYqQ8lDvoAop03TNi%200LhCKRKNNEcNeqUTyYrFeaz3omPUAALAAmAxAA)

Don't forget that you can `curry` it:

```js
type EventSchema = {
    'performTask': (task: string, data: number) => void
};

// Mapping keys of EventSchema to arrays of listener methods
const listeners: { [p in keyof EventSchema]: EventSchema[p][] } = {
    'performTask': []
};

const withListeners = <
    K extends keyof EventSchema,
    Listeners extends Record<K, Array<(...args: Parameters<EventSchema[K]>) => void>>
>(listeners: Listeners,) =>
    (event: K, ...args: Parameters<EventSchema[K]>) =>
        listeners[event].forEach((listener) => listener(...args));

const emitGlobalEvent = withListeners(listeners)

emitGlobalEvent('performTask', 'task', 42)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAygYwBYQLYEMoC8UA3gLABQUVUA5JAE4BmA9vdgCq4DOA1jQFxQAFMG49BXYPQCWiAOYAaKABNcowYgCu2AEYR6ASkIA%20KHGbTlFAL4BuChQD0jqAFlcYMLLlQeEEFxQzIywCMjoWHhQwMxQuPT0uAFBIQA20pJI%20lDYEMAYzMpcFGjMiJJQ6ZmI%20lyCxFAA2mBQsr7%20waFIqJg4uAC6gvDdEX3N-Y39UNaEJBTUtAwsbJy8Ak39NvbkJWUVAO7S%20QAyGcBZ9IFEADzz1ADSUBAAHueIRe0gncPhvXgKdyop2qtSeryQHwAShBSvRlNd7koAIIJJLXIQAOix8TkdSgAAV4rhcudLtcfj1IrhGvd%20sYjARTOZLMZjBRjEIqm9aoJgdzLgoGWzKNQhBAwsBBIioFiMTi8YTEiTauSJaM8DS6ULAQtKmcLlxGuLuv0McsYLhMEJOfqaoYTHqQfRMdj6LiDAZtrtysAntgjgBxVLMHS4VIU2aHE622o2p1cAwOcg4QPB0PhiVCOj6ZYcMQ0JQ0URrJQAFgATAYgA)